# Function returns the outlook email address

Tags: vb.net

is there a function in Vb.net that returns the actual connected address E-mail in outlook. I want only to know which address email is used by the user of my application to check if he has the right to open the application or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your user is in an active directory domain and the e-mail is stored in active directory, this is the easiest route.

Comment: Looking at what you're using it for, it seems to me using e-mail address to authenticate login is an odd approach with potential to be exploited.  An alternative could be to link usage rights to a Google login and use their API to verify (Google) identity.

Comment: you are right its for authentication , but its not a google login its outlook login ( I mean the installed software ). I m looking for a function that can returns the connected email address not from the server but only from the outlook installed software.
thanks in advance